# Domain name explanations

Tags: domains, subdomain, domain-registration, multiple-domains

I recently thought to myself why certain websites have very unique domain names.

Is it possible for a website to have for example `www.aboutus.example.com` instead of `www.example.com/aboutus` ?

Like for Stack Exchange, it has many different domain names? Is that what it's called? Domain names?

For example:

- `http://android.stackexchange.com/`
- `http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/`
- `http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/`

So if I want my website to have quite a few pages, can I actually create a website with

- `www.aboutus.example.com`
- `www.home.example.com`
- `www.contactus.example.com`

What is this actually called and is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand what subdomains are.

When you purchase a domain, you purchase something like `example.com`.

If you see something like `www.example.com` or `aboutus.example.com`, `aboutus` is just a subdomain of `example.com`. When you see something like `www.aboutus.example.com`, `www` is a subdomain of `aboutus.example.com`. When you insert a dot (`.`), you create a subdomain.

When you purchase a domain like `example.com`, you can create several subdomains and sub-subdomains (as you want). For your information, each subdomain represents a different website.

Stack Exchange doesn't have different domain names, the company has the `stackexhange.com` domain name and several subdomains of it.

Comment: Are . and / the same thing. could I go to stackexchange.com/andorid?

Comment: @Qwertieϟ `.` and `/` (subdomains and "subfolders") are implemented very differently technically. Whether a subdomain refers to a subfolder is dependent on the implementation. This is a common setup on some hosts, however, it is not always the case and is not the case with `stackexchange.com/android`.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, when you see names instead of IP Addresses, they are called, in general "domain names". Thus:

- `example.com` is a domain name
- `sub.example.com` is also a domain name
- `srv.sub.example.com` is also a domain name

The `.com` part is called a TLD (Top Level Domain). The `example` part is called 2LD (Second Level Domain) and so on. The higher level domains are generally called "subdomains" of the lower level ones. Thus, referring to the examples above:

- `sub` is a subdomain of `example.com`
- `srv` is a subdomain of `sub.example.com`

Now, in a URI, the parts after the slash after the domain name, is handled by the server who is using the domain name. For example, if we have the URI `http://sub.example.com/about`, the browser contacts the server called `sub.example.com` using the HTTP protocol, informing the server that the browser wants to view an object located in `/about` (note the leading slash).

Is it possible to change the URI from `http://sub.example.com/about` to, let's say `http://about.sub.example.com`? Yes, but one needs a different IP address to ensure that what's returned by the latter is different from what's returned by `http://sub.example.com`. The reason is that HTTP version 1.0 don't provide the full URI in its request, only HTTP version 1.1 actually provide the full URI. Thus, a browser not supporting HTTP version 1.1 will cause the server to be confused and likely receives the wrong page.